# How to build pion mediadevices examples with x264 Windows?

Tags: go, cgo, x264

I am trying to build the pion mediadevices webrtc example utilizing x264 as my video encoder. I am building on a Windows 10 PC. The pion/mediadevices library utilizes pkg-config to locate x264 to build the program. I keep getting this error when building though:

```
# pkg-config --cflags  -- x264
Package x264 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `x264.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'x264' found
pkg-config: exit status 1
```

I downloaded the source code for x264, but there is no x264.pc included. And from my research, it appears x264.pc is only included with libx264. I can't find any way to get libx264 on Windows either. Lastly, what is x264.pc, and what is a .pc file?
Thanks for the help!

Edit: I think I have to build the x264 library first, and I almost got it to work. MinGW was able to compile x264 and give me the x264.pc. But it was all compiled in 32bit, how can I compile the x264 library for 64bit on windows?

Comment: A pc file is used by `pkg-config` as shown the the error output.

Comment: @JimB Oh! What needs to be in that file for pkg-config?